# Websocket nodejs memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, websocket, socket.io, garbage-collection

I'm using node v4.2.1 with socket.io (I have tested even with websocket/ws getting "better" result, but still not enough). At the moment there are few opened connections (hundreads) and the usage percentage of memory is 38% (I'm running on a AWS t2.small Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)).

The server code is embarrising simple (just for test):

```
... declaration ...
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.send("hi");
});
```

As far as the client code is concerned, I'm using the corresponding socket.io version.
How is it possible that sockets occupy all that space in memory?

Moreover, I'm following this post:

http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/

and I run the server with --expose-gc flag but seems doesn't working (Every 30 seconds I force the garbage collector *global.gc*), any guess?

Answer (score 0):

nodejs GC is mostly lazy, eating memory until it hits it's limit of 1.4Gb. In heavy load app it's normal to see a pattern where node process goes up to ~1.4Gb and then fallback to 200Mb.

GC is lazy because it's synchronous (blocking the loop, stopping the full process, bad stuff...).

It's configurable* with `--max-old-space-size` here with 800Mb.

```
node --max-old-space-size=800 app.js
```

In order to decrease (or increase) this limit.

- `--max-old-space-size` actually configure the biggest memory space of node, wich is around 1400 by default, not the GC per say. But when the old space size hit it's limit, it trigger a full GC.